# vb.net method NavigateToString(WebBrowser)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, browser

The method NavigateToString is **available** on `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`

and not in `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`

and im using `winforms` , there is a dll file that can add the "NavigateToString" method to my project?

Comment: Why not just use the Navigate method?

Comment: if im using NavigateToString i can navigate to html code: navigatetostring("<h1>test</h1>");

Answer (score 1):

Instead of NavigateToString(WebBrowser) use [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext) property for that

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<h1>test</h1>";
```